# How to specify which directory to get files from in Tabula Java

Tags: python, linux, tabula

I have this code in python which I use to open with  the subprocess module and proceed to get the data from there but I can't figure out how to OCR a file from a different directory. I've tried putting the complete file path to the directory where the filename should be in the code but it doesn't seem to do the trick. How can I specify which directory to get the files from in Tabula?

```
var = ['java', '-jar', 'tabula-0.9.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar','-p', '1', '-a', '35, 0, 800, 800','-c', '25, 55, 85, 115, 145, 185, 339, 363, 530', file]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifying the full path to the PDF document should be enough. Additionally, you might consider using [tabula-py](https://github.com/chezou/tabula-py), a Python wrapper for `tabula-java`.

Comment: Ok thank you! I will try that out and look into tabula-py as well

Comment: You're welcome. Marking the answer as accepted would be appreciated :)